# Can I travel with a B1/B2 visa in old passport, when new passport has name corrected?

Tags: passports, b1-b2-visas

I have a valid B1/B2 VISA in my old passport, where my full name was written as a single, combined word, such as AAABBB. I was issued a new passport in which I had it changed to AAA as first name and BBB as surname. Can I still travel to US carrying both passports as proof?

Answer (score 1):

This is of relevance

> **I changed my name. Is my U.S. visa with my old name still valid?**
>
> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from the United States..

If your name had not changed and you had just obtained a new passport after expiration of an old one, this would have applied

> **My old passport has already expired. My visa to travel to the United States is still valid but in my expired passport. Do I need to apply for a new visa with my new passport?**
>
> No. If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States with your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged, and is the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose of travel is tourism). Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.). When you arrive at the U.S. port-of-entry (POE, generally an airport or land border) the Customs and Border Protection Immigration Officer will check your visa in the old passport and if s/he decides to admit you into the United States they will stamp your new passport with an admission stamp along with the annotation "VIOPP" (visa in other passport). Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no longer be valid..

Reference: [U.S. Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html)